# installing EclipseFP fails on the URL

Tags: haskell, eclipse-plugin

In my studies I was required to learn Haskell by myself, and to code in Haskell. I searched a lot about how to install plugins for Haskell, and I saw that it can be done on Eclipse development environment, version 3.7 or later. I downloaded this from here: http://filehippo.com/download_eclipse_classic_64/tech/11757/ (if you will go to this site it will be downloaded to your computer immediately!).
I followed up, step by step, after the installation-instructions, which I found here:
http://eclipsefp.github.io/install.html

I added the plugin's URL that was given there, and everything was fine.
But then, when I tried to start using EclipseFP by going to Window > Open perspective > Other... and selecting Haskell - I got the following error:
"problems opening perspective 'net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.HaskellPespective'".
And that it. I actually cannot using EclipseFP...
Does anyone have a solution?
please!

P.S. I also tried installing Haskell on intellij, as someone explained here, but it didn't work either. I didn't knew how to actually open a Haskell program.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

EclipseFP is no longer an active project, so you'll struggle to get support. Most people who use Haskell use emacs or vim. You'll probably find Atom easier to get started with though. Atom with the following packages works for me:

- autocomplete-haskell
- haskell-ghc-mod
- haskell-hoogle
- ide-haskell (this is the main package)
- ide-haskell-cabal
- ide-haskell-repl
- language-haskell

Answer (score 1):

As GarethR says, EclipseFP is no longer active. You might also look at Leksah, which is purpose-written in Haskell for Haskell.